# form POST submit requests show up as get requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

We have a javascript/jQuery form which we submit:

```
var form = jQuery("<form action='http://ourdomain.com/api/setter' method='post' target='response_frame'><input type='text' name='c' value='aaaa'></form>").appendTo(document.body);
form.submit();
```

Corresponding request shows as GET in the IIS logs (and it is missing "c" value because it was supposed to be in the body). Any hints how POST became GET?

I can't repro it locally, it works as expected with POST, it only shows up in IIS logs in productions.

Comment: Probably easier to check what type of request is being sent in your browser's dev tools. E.g. in chrome open the network tab and then submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because IIS adds trailing slash to URL's which cause a 301 redirection. So `POST` becomes `GET`. As a solution try to add a trailing slash to your form action:

```
var form = jQuery("<form action='http://ourdomain.com/api/setter/' method='post' target='response_frame'><input type='text' name='c' value='aaaa'></form>").appendTo(document.body);
form.submit();
```

I hope this will help you.